# Encrypt data with aes-256-cbc with openssl in php

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, php-openssl

I am trying to encrypt hexadecimal data with openssl `aes-256-cbc` in php language. My data length is 32 byte and key length is 32 byte and `iv` is 16 byte **0**.

I used `openssl_encrypt` function to encrypt the hexadecimal data but function output so long I expected. I don't know where is my fault.

Here is the code below:

```
$plainData = "00A40800063D103D202F2400";
$encryptionMethod = "aes-256-cbc";
$encryptionKey = "395f426c0e5bd914375837483b791d80854dd9a19dd86fd189e94ccade60c5b8";
$iv = "0000000000000000";

$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($plainData, $encryptionMethod, $encryptionKey, $iv);

Output: 6e6469763877536e534a4f677168716f67692f684a4166315767534951764f645a575044554f6f4162763333332f6c516d6a397635723566713259444f6e79586137586e366e4f476e7a46765a4b45302b4b4855676961786757556361373932766869584453385749726f3d
```

Expected output length is 32 byte but above output is 216 character string.

Where is the problem above code block?

Comment: *Expected output length is 32 byte?* Source?

Comment: I mean expected output must be like this **2F39F8B92E997DEEAC626E8C878DD163139BA812ABC988A2A1C0D62F524C341B**. This output is 32 byte as Hex. Source is **71CCB433B2891F8F57136C3D2C1F43683D103D202F2400000000000000000009**. It is 32 byte too.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, the provided example is bogus (output for that code is not even remotely similar to the one you claim) and your usage of IV is wrong, among other things. Cryptography is hard, just use a vetted library to do it for you.

Comment: @Narf, do you have any library that you can suggest to me?

Comment: Asking for recommendations on this site is off-topic, but defuse/php-encryption and paragonie/halite come to mind.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I will examine them. On the other hand, I asked a question about encryption and you answered me that "Your encryption method is wrong". You said to me that you should use a library. Because of your answer, I asked library that you recommend. I think it is natural. Do I need to ask another question to learn what encryption libraries that you recommend? Nevertheless, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it is natural. And I did give you suggestions, because with cryptography in particular, I'd rather do that than leave you do something horribly wrong. But I am also inclined to mention the site rules, because if you come to ask for recommendations next time, your question will 100% be closed - I'm doing you a favor by warning you about this, don't get all defensive about it.

Comment: Okey, I understand. Thank you. I will keep your suggestions and warnings in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The length is different in size because of so called *padding*. The padding used by default is PKCS#7 compatible padding. This padding is always added; this way the padding can be distinguished from possible (binary) plaintext.

If you already know that the ciphertext is always a multiple of the block size then you can use `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` as option both during encryption and decryption; you will then be responsible for making sure that the plaintext is a multiple of the block size during encryption.

---

It is possible to use AES-CBC with an all zero IV, but remember that this leaks information about the plaintext: repeated plaintext blocks at the start of the plaintext message can be identified. The only way to reliably use an all zero IV is to make sure that the first plaintext block is never identical *or* to change the key on every call.

Also note that CBC mode is malleable - if the ciphertext or plaintext can be altered by an attacker the simple encryption mode you're describing is bound to have security issues.